# Pytorch Loaded model giving inconsistent results

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I am playing around with code from this Github repository https://github.com/jindongwang/Pytorch-CapsuleNet.

After training the model for 5 epochs, I got an accuracy of 99.2% on the test dataset. So I saved model using the following code:

```
torch.save(capsule_net.state_dict(),"capsnet_mnist_state.pt")
```

I tried loading the model back in another machine with the below code:

```
capsnet = CapsNet(Config())
capsnet.load_state_dict(torch.load('capsnet_mnist_state.pt'))
capsnet.eval()
```

Now the model predicts the 0 has the output for every input. Is there anything wrong with way I saved the model or loaded the model?.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong with the way you saved or the way you load your model.

But I happened to see the same problem because I didn't initialise some parameters, so they were stuck to 'None' even after loading the state dict.

I would suggest to look into the loaded state_dict to see if any parameters makes no sense.

Hope this help.